# Can a user in parachain construct an XCM msg with a DescendOrigin instr and the dest to be the Relay Chain

Tags: xcm

This is an extension question on [Remote XCM calls execution via individual signed Account](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/9712/xcm-remote-transactions-call/9718#9718)

As most of derivitive Accounts are either from Relay Chain to parachain and getting the derived Account you just hash

`let acc = hash("ParentChain",ParaId,AccountId32,Address)`

But what if the messsage is coming from the ParaA and Alice wants to have a derivitive Account in RelayChain by including the DescendOrigin instruction.

```
   let msg = Xcm(vec![
          Descendorigin(..),
          ...other instructions
   ])

   paraAXcm::send_xcm(Here,Parent,msg);
```