# Best practices for generating sovereign account ids from XCM locations

Tags: xcm

The XCM builder crate provides various converters for generating sovereign account ids from MultiLocations.

Many parachains, including system parachains, use the following converter:

A:

```rust
pub type LocationToAccountId = (
        // The parent (Relay-chain) origin converts to the parent `AccountId`.
        ParentIsPreset<AccountId>,
        // Sibling parachain origins convert to AccountId via the `ParaId::into`.
        SiblingParachainConvertsVia<Sibling, AccountId>,
        // Straight up local `AccountId32` origins just alias directly to `AccountId`.
        AccountId32Aliases<RelayNetwork, AccountId>,
);
```

However, more recently a new converter was introduced, which seems to be more comprehensive, as supports converting nested consensus systems within sibling parachains:

B:

```rust
HashedDescription<AccountId, DescribeFamily<DescribeAllTerminal>>,
```

Converter B doesn't support converting local AccountId32's though, so there isn't a total overlap.

Therefore it seems we should use this aggregate converter going forward, to remain compatible with existing sovereign accounts:

C:

```
pub type LocationToAccountId = (
        // The parent (Relay-chain) origin converts to the parent `AccountId`.
        ParentIsPreset<AccountId>,
        // Sibling parachain origins convert to AccountId via the `ParaId::into`.
        SiblingParachainConvertsVia<Sibling, AccountId>,
        // Straight up local `AccountId32` origins just alias directly to `AccountId`.
        AccountId32Aliases<RelayNetwork, AccountId>,
        // Convert nested locations within sibling parachains.
        HashedDescription<AccountId, DescribeFamily<DescribeAllTerminal>>,
);
```

Is option (C) the best way going forward? I'm also wondering if perhaps the implementation of `HashDescription` could be extended to also handle  `AccountId32Aliases`?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Oops, I've updated to be more clear about my question.

Comment: Does this answer your question:https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/9712/xcm-remote-transactions-call